# How to position 'Signature tab' using Docusign such that it does not overlap with 'Anchor String'

Tags: docusignapi

1) I am currently using Anchor Tagging in my application.

2) The tab definition I am using is as follows

```
"tabs": {
"signHereTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:",
    "anchorXOffset": "1",
    "anchorYOffset": "0",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
    "anchorUnits": "inches"
}]
```

}

3) Given that 'anchorXOffset' is always computed from starting point of the 'Anchor string', I am currently facing an issue in which the Anchor string is getting overlapped by the signature tab.

[image]

4) This means that depending on the 'font size' of my 'anchor string' the 'signature tag' may or may not overlap the 'anchor string'

5) QUESTION : Is there any way such that 'anchorXOffset' is computed from end point of the 'anchor string'?

If Not, is there any way where we can place the 'signature tab' dynamically with respect to the 'Anchor string', such that the font size of the 'anchor string' does not affect the positioning of 'signature tab' and 'anchor string' is not overlapped by the 'signature tab'?

Comment: Might not be ideal but can the signature tab go UNDER the consultant string instead of next to it?  That way it wouldn't matter what font is being used.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign doesn't know the layout or font sizes of the source documents, so the answer to your question is no.

What I'd suggest is that you place the anchor string directly adjacent to the label for the tag. That way if the font size of the label string is changed, the anchor string will be re-positioned too.

I realize that since the anchor string is invisible to the casual source document owner, they might mess up the anchor string when updating the document.

Another solution is to first make the source documents using PDF Form fields. The form fields can then be converted to tags. But using Acrobat or similar to create/manage the source documents is obviously more difficult and expensive than using Word or similar.